# Best way to check array elements contain specific value

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, contains

I have a list of objects and have to search through this list if it contains a specific value. The specific values are all saved in an array. What should I set for `allValuesFromArray` in the code below so that it would function accordingly?

```
List<ownClass> objectList;
String[] specificValueArray = {"value0","value1","value2","value3"};
for (ownClass object:objectlist){
    if (object.getSomeValue() == allValuesFromArray){
            //some code
        }
    }
```

Comment: If your list is sorted, then you can use `Collections.binarySearch`

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can use:

```
if (Arrays.asList(specificValueArray).contains(object.getSomeValue())){
    ...
}
```

This will return `true` if `object.getSomeValue()` is inside `specificValueArray` (remember to
`import java.util.Arrays;`)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
if (!objectList.retainAll(Arrays.asList(specificValueArray)).isEmpty()) {
    //some code
}
```

This disguises the complexity a bit, in that this is O(n^2), but is clean and readable.